# How to configure 'ngProgress' as loader in my project [ngbp boilerplate]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using 'ngbp' (https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp) angular boilerplate to build my project and I'm trying to make ngProgress work to show the loader when changing from section to section.

I've installed ngProgress through bower. I have css and js in place.

In my app.js I have this:

```
(function(app) {

    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    }]);

    app.run(function () {});

    app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    }]);

}(angular.module("grinFood", [
    'grinFood.home',
    'grinFood.about',
    'grinFood.menu',
    'grinFood.catering',
    'grinFood.takeithome',
    'grinFood.contact',
    'templates-app',
    'templates-common',
    'ui.router.state',
    'ui.router',
    'ngProgress',
])));
```

Then for example my catering.js looks like this:

```
(function(app) {

    app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('catering', {
            url: '/catering',
            views: {
                "main": {
                    controller: 'CateringController',
                    templateUrl: 'catering/catering.tpl.html'
                }
            },
            data:{ pageTitle: 'Catering' }
        });
    }]);

    app.controller('CateringController', ['$scope', function ($scope, ngProgress) {

        var init = function() {
            // A definitive place to put everything that needs to run when the controller starts. Avoid
            //  writing any code outside of this function that executes immediately.
            ngProgress.start();
        };

        init();
    }]);

}(angular.module("grinFood.catering", [
    'ui.router'
])));
```

That is when I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined`
Also tried to put the ngprogress in the controller in app.js but I can't make it work.

You can watch the error here: http://ticketcomunicacion.com/grinfood/#/menu

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, ngbp looks like it's out of date. Try http://yeoman.io/ Secondly, I'm clueless why do you wrap `app` with a function? This is pointless, unless that you have a other library with a conflict.

Do you use minifiers? If yes try use one that is aware of anugarjs dependency framework. Basically, you need to specify your dependency correctly

`['$scope', function ($scope, ngProgress)`

change to

```
function ($scope, ngProgress)
```

or

```
['$scope', 'ngProgress', function ($scope, ngProgress)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not injecting `ngProgress` into the controller properly.

Instead of this:

```
app.controller('CateringController', ['$scope', function ($scope, ngProgress) {
```

You need to do this:

```
app.controller('CateringController', ['$scope', 'ngProgress', function ($scope, ngProgress) {
```

Note, a while back I switched to using [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate), it's a very nice way to avoid these errors. I actually use [ng-annotate-rails](https://github.com/kikonen/ngannotate-rails). These will help you avoid these types of mistakes in the future and clean up your code a bit. I highly recommend either one!